# Extract text between matching parentheses

Tags: r, regex, extract, stringr

Consider the following example:

```
x <- "something('pineapple', 'orange', y = c('peach', 'banana'), z = 'lemon'), something(v = c('apple', 'pear'), z = c('cherry', 'strawberry', 'grape'))"
```

I want to extract the segments encapsulated by `something(` and its matching `)`. Thus, the respective function should extract `"something('pineapple', 'orange', y = c('peach', 'banana'), z = 'lemon')"` and `"something(v = c('apple', 'pear'), z = c('cherry', 'strawberry', 'grape'))"` in this example. There can be any number of parentheses within `something()`. Thus, I cannot simply extract everything from `something(` to the next `)`. That would e.g. return the first segment as `"something('pineapple', 'orange', y = c('peach', 'banana')"`.

I am essentially looking to fill in the regex placeholder in

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "something\\(<text until matching parenthesis>")
```

Comment: What about `strsplit(x, ', (?=something)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]`?

Comment: Welcome, I put it as an answer with some explanation added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` with a regex looking for

- `,` a comma
- `\\s*` zero or more spaces
- `(?=something)` a positive lookahead for `"something"`

```
strsplit(x, ',\\s*(?=something)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "something('pineapple', 'orange', y = c('peach', 'banana'), z = 'lemon')"  
# [2] "something(v = c('apple', 'pear'), z = c('cherry', 'strawberry', 'grape'))"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- "something('pineapple', 'orange', y = c('peach', 'banana'), z = 'lemon'), something(v = c('apple', 'pear'), z = c('cherry', 'strawberry', 'grape'))"
```

Comment: Or simply `str_split(x, ', (?=something)')[[1]]`, since OP seems to be working in `tidyverse`

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion (`?1` or `?R`) to match balanced constructs or nested constructs.

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("something(\\(([^()]|(?1))*\\))", x, perl=TRUE))
#[[1]]
#[1] "something('pineapple', 'orange', y = c('peach', 'banana'), z = 'lemon')"  
#[2] "something(v = c('apple', 'pear'), z = c('cherry', 'strawberry', 'grape'))"
```

Where `a(?1)z` is a recursion which match one or more letters `a` followed by exactly the same number of letters `z`.

Comment: That is even closer to what I was looking for. Thanks.